# The relation between usernames and their number

Tags: usb, permissions

I am little curious about the relation between usernames and the numbers they use internal. I am not fit in this at all, so please don't hit me. When I set up a system and add some user, let's say user number 5 is "black" and gets his ID. He get system administtrator privileges. Then on another pc user no. 5 is "guest" with standard prvileges. "black" makes a backup on an usb-stick. "guest gets it and tries to copy the data. Because they have the same ID, can he succeed?

Answer (score 1):

UID's are used on the file system. This is commonly a problem if you have NFS volumes shared across many computers, as it follows UID and not username. Also, different distros may start UID numbering at different points.

But yes, what you say is in effect true. Note that Unix FS ACL's does not protect against someone having a offline copy of the data. They're free to mount the drive on a box where they're root. ACLs protect data from unintended access while the OS is running.